# What does kchip/s datarate mean?

Tags: discrete-signals, electrical-signal

I am working in w mbus and came across this term kchip/s in datarate like 37.768 kchip/s what does the unit specify?

Comment: Does [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_(CDMA)) help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protocols like w-mbus or Zigbee typically use some form of frequency-spreading like [DSSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-sequence_spread_spectrum). In DSSS we do not send symbols directly using some pulse shape and encoding the information in the sign but instead we use a rapidly alternating sequence of $\pm 1$ as a pulse. This leads to an increase in the occupied bandwidth ("spreading"). The receiver multiplies the incoming signal with the same sequence, coherently combining back all the information ("de-spreading"), which overall increases the robustness to fading and reduces the peak power spectral density. See the link for more details.

What it means practically is that each symbol is further sub-divided in time domain into smaller units called "chips". The rate at which these chips are sent is called chip rate which itself is a measure for the occupied bandwidth. For instance, a chip rate of 500 kchips/s would mean that 500'000 chips per second are sent, which requires something like 500 kHz (practically more, due to the required guard bands).

If you want to know your data rate, you need to know the code (i.e., how many chips per symbol are used) and the modulation and coding scheme (i.e., how many bits per symbol are sent).

For example, [this TI reference design](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/tidua08a/tidua08a.pdf) states 100kcps with 11-bit DSSS coding and 2-FSK modulation. This gives 100kchips/s / 11chips/symbol * 1bit/symbol ~ 9kbit/s (minus packet overhead).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer Mr.Florian

Comment: Glad to hear it helped!